# Angular on $scope.add add cookie/localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Im wondering what's the best way to save localy new todo for example.

I have this code:

```
angular.module('contactManager')
  .controller('AddCtrl', function ( $scope, $location, $cookieStore) {
    $scope.contact = {};
    $scope.add = function() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.contact));
      $cookieStore.put('todo-'+$scope.contact.index,'value');
      $scope.contacts.push($scope.contact);
      $location.url('/');
    };
  });
```

Is it possible to know inside $scope.add ( when form is accepted ) index of the our new todo item ( something like I did upper -> $scope.contact.index ) ?

And what is the best way to store it local and send to db?

I was googling for good answer for more than 1 hour and didn't find anything satisfying

Comment: Just found I can do that this way:  var idx = $scope.contacts.length + 1;
      $cookieStore.put('todo-'+idx,'value'); But maybe its not the best idea.

Comment: You can use a simple variable that has 0, -- lets say, `$scope.index` -- as a initial value and, then, use `$cookieStore.put('todo-'+$scope.index++,'value');`